# Writing to a csv using pandas with filters

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

I'm using the pandas library to load in a csv file using Python.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("movies.csv")
```

I'm then checking the columns for specific values or statements, such as:

```
viewNum = df["views"] >= 1000
starringActorNum = df["starring"] > 3
df["title"] = df["title"].astype("str")
titleLen = df["title"].str.len() <= 10
```

I want to create a new csv file using the criteria above, but am unsure how to do that as well as how to combine all those attributes into one csv.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You want to have your data frame filtered with all of the constraints you present there being applied in parallel?

Comment: Yes. I have a .csv dataset I've loaded in, but want to filter out some of the content based on certain criteria (hence, the examples above). I just don't know how to translate all my constraints to a csv

Answer (score 5):

Combine the boolean masks using `&` (bitwise-and):

```
mask = viewNum & starringActorNum & titleLen
```

Select the rows of `df` where `mask` is True:

```
df_filtered = df.loc[mask]
```

Write the DataFrame to a csv:

```
df_filtered.to_csv('movies-filtered.csv')
```

---

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("movies.csv")

viewNum = df["views"] >= 1000
starringActorNum = df["starring"] > 3
df["title"] = df["title"].astype("str")
titleLen = df["title"].str.len() <= 10

mask = viewNum & starringActorNum & titleLen
df_filtered = df.loc[mask]

df_filtered.to_csv('movies-filtered.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`panda.DataFrame.query()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) interface.  It allows text string queries, and is very fast for large data sets.

Something like this should work:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("movies.csv")

# the len() method is not available to query, so pre-calculate
title_len = df["title"].str.len()

# build the data frame and send to csv file, title_len is a local variable
df.query('views >= 1000 and starring > 3 and @title_len <= 10').to_csv(...)
```